# call function by address from dll

Tags: c++, function, dll

good evening!

i stumbled upon a very specific c/c++ problem and i hope you can guide me in the right direction! ;)

what should be accomplished:
i want toinvestigate a methode for a runtime-optimisation for a loop-fusion.
So, collect an amount of loop-bodys (the lambdas) and execute them in one loop (for the first step. later, there should be advanced optimisations). So i need a methode to execute a variable amount of functions in a dynamic loaded .dll.

What i want to archieve:

i save an flexible amount of lambda-functions as std::function.
Now i want to create a .dll at runtime, which uses this lambda-functions.
So, i recieve the addresses of this function by calling  (void*)(&fn.fn()).
This is going to a file, this file is compilled as .dll and importet in the c++ Application.
But calling the functions by their address unfortunately fails..
Maybe i am  on the absolutly wrong scent, i hope, you can help me!

Now the relevant parts of the code:
The simplified output-file, which should be compiled

```
    #include <functional>
    #include <iostream>
     extern "C"{
      __declspec(dllexport)  void doLoop() {
          using fn_t = std::function<void(size_t)>;
          // get the address by calling in the host application: (void*)(&fn.fn())
          auto &fn = *((fn_t*)0x00835DE8); 
          fn(1);
     }
   }
```

The Compilation using MinGW in the host

```
    if (system(("g++ -std=c++11 -DBUILD_DLL -Wall   -c lib" + identifier_ + ".cpp").c_str()) == -1)
            throw std::runtime_error("Error in lib compile.");
    if (system(("g++  -shared -o lib" + identifier_ + ".dll  libtest.o  ").c_str()) == -1)
            throw std::runtime_error("Error in lib link."); 


     HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary(L"libtest.dll");
     if (!hInst){
        std::cerr << "..." << std::endl;
    }
    //"typedef void(__stdcall* FNPTR)();" in the header
    FNPTR fn = (FNPTR)GetProcAddress(hInst, "doLoop");
    if (!fn){
        std::cerr << "..." << std::endl;
    }
    fn();
```

The function-call fn() crashes with 
"0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0xCDCDCDCD

Thank you very much in advance!

Best Greetings,
Armin

Comment: You have explained, what you believe to be a solution. Yet you failed to explain, what problem you are ultimately trying to accomplish. From the sounds of it, you are going for a solution that isn't ideal. If you want to understand what went wrong, have a look at the [Win32 Debug CRT Heap Internals](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html), and look up the bit pattern `0xCDCDCDCD`. Hint: This is uninitialized heap memory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the link!
I will add the final goal in the question!

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Just pass a `std::function` when you call `doLoop` and if you need to pass more than one stuff them in a `std::vector`.

Comment: No one here can possibly have any idea what's at the address 0x00835DE8, but the fact that you need to cast it back and forth strongly suggests that it's not something you really want to be there.